# UIActivityIndicatorView displaying after presentViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

Currently I have a UITableView filled with JPG files that are gathered from a server.

The problem is when I select on a cell the activity view controller takes a while to appear due to the size of JPG being around 3mb.

What I am trying to do is put an activity indicator in the cell so when it has been selected it will display the indicator until the activity view controller is displayed then disappear.

However what is happening at the moment is when i select the cell the image is downloaded and partially freezes while doing so, then the activity view controller pops up allowing for "save to camera roll" but when the controller comes up then so does the indicator at the wrong time. I have tried to start the animation before the view controller is displayed as well.

Here is my code so far

```
// creating spinner activity

UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
UITableViewCell *Cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
Cell.accessoryView = spinner;

//popup menu for save to camera roll
UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]]];

UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:image]
                                  applicationActivities:nil];

//check to see if jpg file
if([ext isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {


    [spinner startAnimating];

    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES
                     completion:^{}];

}
```

Comment: This is a fairly common issue people face with table views, you need to load the images asynchronously. [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) is the best option.

Comment: Im not really sure on SDWebImage, i tried to follow the instructions for installing on there github however when I had done all the steps and went to build I got multiple errors, could you provide me with any other links to get it to work? @Mar0ux

Comment: Two things on SDWebImage: `iOS 5.0 minimum deployement version` and use ARC. But I'm confused: is your problem only the freeze when loading images, or something else?

Comment: What happends is I select the image cell, it does nothing for about 10 seconds then the activity list is displayed allowing for saving to camera roll. @Mar0ux

Comment: Yeah, so the only problem is synchronous image download. You should switch to SDWebImage. Its fairly easy and super convenient.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're downloading the image synchronously:

```
UIImage * image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]]];
```

You need to change this to an asynchronous download and present the view controller after the download is complete.

Comment: I am not loading a new view controller, i loading an Activity View Controller like this........http://www.techotopia.com/images/d/df/Iphone_ios6_facebook_example_chooser.png @Wain

Comment: You're still using presentViewController: and that needs to be done once the asynchronous download is complete.